# PERL, choose data from more columns in one time?

Tags: perl

can you help me? I created txt file. There are 4 columns.

```
1   -7  8,2 8,1
1   -5  8,4 8
1   -3  8,5 8,2
2   -6  8,4 8,2
3   -5  8,4 8,2
3   -4  8,4 8,3
5   -1  8,5 8,3
5   1   8,4 8,6
```

I need out:
1 0 0 0 0 -7 8,2 8,1
when in first column is for example 1 , out is 1 0 0 0 0 . if 2 out is 0 1 0 0 0 . if 3: 0 0 1 0 0 . if 4: 0 0 0 1 0 . if 5: 0 0 0 0 1 and continue data from next columns.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;
    my $i = shift @fields;
    my @bools = (0) x 5;
    $bools[$i-1] = 1;
    unshift @fields, @bools;

    print join(' ', @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
1   -7  8,2 8,1
1   -5  8,4 8
1   -3  8,5 8,2
2   -6  8,4 8,2
3   -5  8,4 8,2
3   -4  8,4 8,3
5   -1  8,5 8,3
5   1   8,4 8,6
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0 0 -7 8,2 8,1
1 0 0 0 0 -5 8,4 8
1 0 0 0 0 -3 8,5 8,2
0 1 0 0 0 -6 8,4 8,2
0 0 1 0 0 -5 8,4 8,2
0 0 1 0 0 -4 8,4 8,3
0 0 0 0 1 -1 8,5 8,3
0 0 0 0 1 1 8,4 8,6
```

Comment: `print join(' ', @fields), "\n";` could be replaced by `print "@fields\n";`.

Comment: Yeah, I will often avoid interpolation of arrays with beginners, because I'd rather not have to explain about [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) or other special variables.  Besides, I don't know if/what delimiter he'd want, so demonstrating [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) is a teachable moment.

Comment: Good point. Perl has too many features that could confuse beginners.

Comment: Great!!! thank you but i will be next from output creat this: 1 0 0 0 0 -7 8,2 8,1 1 0 0 0 0 -5 8,4 8 1 0 0 0 0 -3 8,5 8,2 0 1 0 0 0 -6 8,4 8,2 (join three line to input and every 4 line to output )

Comment: @user3549392 Well speaking of special variables, if you want to do line number based logic, perl automatically creates a variable [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) that holds the _"Current line number for the last filehandle accessed."_  That with the modules operator [`%`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) should enable you to create that logic.